# Bash utility to track the start and end (duration) of tasks?

Tags: linux, time-management, bash, real-time, timer

Can some one recommend a course for tracking the duration of a task from bash?

Hopefully different tasks.

Comment: does https://linux.die.net/man/1/time suit your needs?

Answer (score 0):

Late to this question, but you might like https://github.com/nuex/t

I am not the author of it, but have used it. It works well.